# Array index access from metatable field/method

Tags: c++, lua

I have some metatables that reflect some C++ classes/structs. I usually rely on __index to get called for any fields/methods for the object and resolve them in one function.

The difficulty I'm having is when I want to pass parameters to a field, like so:

```
anim = playerInfo.animations
while anim do

  print (anim)

  numstates = anim.numstates
  for i = 1, numstates do

    state = anim.states(i)  <--- This line right here is the issue
    print(state)

  end

  anim = anim.next

end
```

Here is the relevant C code:

```
static const struct luaL_Reg objanimationlib_m[] = {
    {"__tostring", objanimation2string},
    {"__index", objanimationget},
    {"__newindex", objanimationset},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

    luaL_newmetatable(L, "objanimation");
    lua_pushvalue(L, -1); // duplicates the metatable
    luaL_setfuncs(L, objanimationlib_m, 0);
```

Inside the __index function:

```
else if (!strcmp(field, "states"))
{
    int number = (int)luaL_checknumber(L, 3) - 1; // -1 cuz Lua is not 0-based
    if (number >= anim->numstates)
        return 0;

    PushUserdata(&anim->states[number], "objstate");
}
```

Running the script, I get an error:

```
Warning: [string "test.lua"]:13: bad argument #3 to '__index' (number expected, got no value)
```

I feel like I'm missing something stupidly simple. What is it?

Edit: Here's my solution, inside the __index function:

```
else if (!strcmp(field, "states"))
{
    lua_newtable(L);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < anim->numstates; i++)
    {
          PushUserdata(&anim->states[i], "objstate");
          lua_rawseti(L, -2, i+1);
    }
}
```

This returns a table full of userdata elements. Might be expensive, so this would also increase performance:

```
anim = playerInfo.animations
while anim do

  print (anim)

  numstates = anim.numstates
  states = anim.states
  for i = 1, numstates do

    print(states[i])

  end

  anim = anim.next

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`state = anim.states(i)`

is equivalent to

`do local f=anim.states; state=f(i) end`

and so your metamethod never sees `i`.

In other words, the index metamethod receives two arguments, the table and the key. What it returns is not necessarily subject to any metamethods, unless you make it explicitly so.

I'd go for defining `__len` returning `numstates` and for `__call` to handle `anim.states(i)`, so that you code can be written

```
  for i = 1, #anim do
    state = anim(i)
    print(state)
  end
```

Comment: This is a great solution that might come in handy for other situations. For this particular one, I don't want to break the syntax from the underlying implementation, so I just need to compose a whole table of userdata to return. (anim may contain other arrays). Thank you!